# Solve the complex equation z^2 + ((2 + i)/5)z + 1/11 == 0

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I have tried to solve this in mathematica but cant find the right way.
I used 
`ComplexExpand[z^2 + ((2 + i)/5) z + 1/11]` which gave the result `1/11 + (2 z)/5 + (i z)/5 + z^2`.

Then i tried to solve it and it gave me the roots `{{z -> 1/10 (-2 - i - Sqrt[-56 + 44 i + 11 i^2]/Sqrt[11])}, {z -> 1/10 (-2 - i + Sqrt[-56 + 44 i + i^2]/Sqrt[11])}}`

Do you have any tips how I can solve it in a better way?

Comment: Note: this was x-posted to Wolfram Community (where it may get closed)

Comment: First of all, likely `i` should be `I` (the imaginary unit in *Mathematica* is capital-I). Secondly, what do you mean by "better"? This solution seems perfectly fine to me (once `i` is replaced by `I`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"i" in Mathematica is "I"

```
Solve[z^2 + ((2 + I)/5) z + 1/11 == 0, {z}, Complexes]
```

> {{z -> (1/55 + I/110) (-11 + Sqrt[-11 + 176 I])}, {z -> (-(1/55) - I/
>         110) (11 + Sqrt[-11 + 176 I])}}

Answer (score -1):

`i` is not the same as $i$  (Esc + ii + Esc), resp. `I` Simple i is not an imaginary unit, for Wolfram.

Try

```
Solve[z^2 + ((2 + I)/5) z + 1/11 == 0, z]
```

Result is now

$$  \left\{\left\{z\to \left(\frac{1}{55}+\frac{i}{110}\right) \left(-11+\sqrt{-11+176 i}\right)\right\},\left\{z\to \left(-\frac{1}{55}-\frac{i}{110}\right) \left(11+\sqrt{-11+176 i}\right)\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: I already posted that...

Comment: Yes. +- at the same time :D